# Inserting / deleting elements in array by user input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm a newbie at Java programming. I would like to ask how could I insert / delete the certain input from the user into the arraylist I generated. And it should display the new list that formed I already had a code.. but it's not working well.. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class New1 {
    public static InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    public static BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(r);

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
        ArrayList employees = new ArrayList();
        employees.add("A");
        employees.add("B");
        employees.add("C");
        employees.add("D");
        employees.add("E");

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Lists of Employees");
        System.out.println ("What do you want to do?:");
        System.out.println ("1 - Display list. \n2 - Insert New Name. \n3 - Delete an item. \n4 - Nothing." + "\n ");
        int task = scan1.nextInt();

        if (task==1) {
            System.out.println ("Contents of Employees:" + employees);
        } else if (task==2) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Current list is " + employees);
                System.out.println("Add more? (y/n) ");
                if (scan1.next().startsWith("y")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter : ");
                    employees.add(scan1.next());
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);

            System.out.println("List is " + employees);
            String[] arr = employees.toArray(new String[0]);
            System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
```

I really need help here. >.<

Comment: "_but it's not working well_" isn't very specific...

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: What does it do now and what should it do?

Comment: it's fixed naw. thanks to Rajhput Adi.. 
back then, it gives me an error of incompatible string.. something.
At the line: "String[] arr = employees.toArray(new String[0]);"

My only problem now is deleting an element in my array list by the user's input. >.<

Answer (score 0):

First thing there are some compile time errors in your code.
at last line of code, '}' is missing. class block is not closed.

Second, Use below line, 
String[] arr = (String[]) employees.toArray(new String[0]);
instead of 
 String[] arr = employees.toArray(new String[0]);

as toArray(new String[0]) will return an object and you are storing it in array. So , you have to typecast it into array.Now, it will work fine.

Comment: waah. thanks. TwT

Can I have a sample line for deleting array elements? It's just all I need now. >.<

Comment: I meant "deleting an array element in my original array list by the user's input".. >.<

Comment: you can use remove(object) method to delete an array element.e.g employees.remove(scan1.next());
this will work for you perfectly.

Comment: one more thing A while loop might never execute a statement if the expression is false but a do while will always execute the statement at least once. so, if you want proper results use while loop. Otherwise you can also manage do-while loop with break and continue. :)

Comment: does replacing "employees.add(scan1.next());" with "employees.remove(scan1.next());" works well? o.o

Answer (score 0):

You should parameterized the list initialization otherwise the following piece of code won't compile: `String[] arr = employees.toArray(new String[0]);`

Although you can explicitly cast the right-hand expression to `String[]`, it's not a good practice and disregards the intent of generics to catch potential errors at compile time.

I would do this:

```
List<String> employees = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and instead of `0`, would use size of list to initialize size of the array being created:

```
String[] arr = employees.toArray(new String[employees.size()]);
```

Comment: so I would just erase that
String[] arr = employees.toArray(new String[0]); ??

Comment: Yes, use `String[] arr = employees.toArray(new String[employees.size()]);` instead.

Comment: can you help me with the deleting an array element by user's input? o.o